# NSDictionary objectForKey/valueForKey already formatted?

Tags: cocoa, formatting, nsdictionary

I am receiving JSON-Data and convert it into a Dictionary.
Printing the Dictionary results in the Following description:

```
Objekt: {
author = blub;
authorUID = 28084;
date = "31.07.10";
numVotes = 0;
postUID = 30931;
text = "... <b>Atemtest</b> durchf\U00c3\U00bchren m\U00c3\U00bcssen?...";
timestamp = 1280585555;}
```

What I want is to replace the occurences of e.g. `\U00c3\U00bc` with `\U00bc`.

That's where I'm stuck. `[dictionary objectForKey:@"text"]` returns an already formatted String like `<b>Atemtest</b> durchfÃ¼hren zu mÃ¼ssen?`

valueForKey behaves the same.

Comment: A quick solution was doing an UTF8 decode on the server-side... but I would still like to know how one would do this on the iphone-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both outputs are just different representations of the same underlying `NSString` object in the dictionary, which I believe is already recoded as UTF-16 from whatever it was in the JSON.

As described by Peter Hosey's answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555653/how-can-i-escape-unicode-characters-in-a-nsstring), the output from `NSDictionary` is encoding the string so that it conforms to the expected textual representation of a plist.

In your case, it sounds like you probably don't really want to go back to that representation (although if you do then have a look at the accepted answer to the aforementioned question), but instead do the substitution directly in the NSString, something like this:

```
NSString* oldStr = @"\u00c3\u00bc";
NSString* newStr = @"\u00bc";

NSString* text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"text"];
NSString* replaced = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:oldStr withString:newStr];
```

The `\uXXXX` sequences in the source code will be converted into the relevant UTF-16 characters in the `NSString` constants, and these will then be matched and substituted in the target.

Comment: that's my problem, using the stringByReplacingOccurences didn't work. But I think the question is answered by the related question.