# Removing &#39; in a parsed string in objective c

Tags: objective-c, json, string, parsing, character-encoding

In my Objective C program I am parsing a Json into a string. But in the result string I'm getting

I & # 39 ; ve

intsead of

> I've

Can you suggest how this this could be reformatted to show ' instead of & # 39 ;

Comment: see this you might find your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555653/how-can-i-escape-unicode-characters-in-a-nsstring.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the open source Google Tolbox for Mac `NSString+HTML` [category](http://google-toolbox-for-mac.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString+HTML.h). It contains an number of methods to work with HTML entities in this way. (Implementation file located [here](http://google-toolbox-for-mac.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString+HTML.m)).

Comment: Thanks! But My application is for the iPhone. Is there something I could used for that?

Comment: @bluemachine It should work for either platform, you'll also need the `GTMDefines` header. (http://google-toolbox-for-mac.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/GTMDefines.h)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether this is the only case or you need a more general solution. For just this case, you can use :

```
[inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" & # 39 ; " withString:@"'"];
```